# How do operator/wheel groups work on FreeBSD?

Tags: permissions, freebsd

On FreeBSD 12.0-RELEASE-p3 `ls -l /dev/ada1` gives me:

```
crw-r-----  1 root  operator [skipped] /dev/ada1
```

If I use the command `gpart recover /dev/ada1` from a non-root user account, who is in the group `operator` (and `wheel`), gpart *does* the recovery. It *definitely* writes on the disk.

But why does the non-root user not just have read permissions for the disk? The group `operator` has only read permissions for `/dev/ada1`!

The  sudoers file only consists of:

```
% grep -v '^#' /usr/local/etc/sudoers | grep -v '^$'
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Check /usr/local/etc/sudoers

Comment: @VladimirBotka I don't see how this can be the reason…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gpart(1)` program doesn't write anything to `/dev/ada1`.

It does all its operations by issuing `GEOM_CTL` ioctls on `/dev/geom.ctl`. In order to use `ioctl(2)` on a device file, you don't need write permissions to it; you only need to be able to open() it in read-only mode. And the `operator` group has read permissions on `/dev/geom.ctl`.